# How to change DELETE_RULE to CASCADE for all tables?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I have tried:

```
use information_schema
update referential_constraints set delete_rule='cascade';
```

but got the following error:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

I have all privileges.

Comment: Are you sure you have all privileges? It looks like you accidentally deleted some. Can you post the output of `SHOW GRANTS;` (run in a MySQL console under `root` MySQL user).

Comment: It is bacause information_schema cannot be modified. You should alter each table, one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Information_schema` is exactly that: information. It reports on the the objects in your databases

To changes the object in your database you need to run ALTERs on them. You can't do it via the `Information_schema` views

Comment: You can use the `information_schema` to "build" the `ALTER` statements you'll then have to run on your table's foreign keys, but that's all it'll help you with. As @gbn says, you'll still have to execute several `ALTER` statements.

Comment: @Romain: yes, there are probably scripts already out there to do this

Comment: I wouln't be surprised. Though they wouldn't be terribly hard to write from scratch either... :)

Answer (score 0):

Okey, that is

select 'alter table ',table_name, 'drop foreign key ',constraint_name,';',
'alter table ',table_name, 'add constraint',constraint_name,'foreign key',
'(',column_name,') references',referenced_table_name,'(',referenced_column_name,') on delete cascade;' 
from key_column_usage where referenced_table_name is not null;